# How to swap two numbers using javascript function with one parameter

Tags: javascript

My Requirement is 
I want to display this output when I gave `a(0)` the output should come 5 and when I gave `a(5)` the output should come 0.

```
 a(0) = 5  
 a(5) = 0
```

like this
Hint:
Using this function 
function A(num){} 
like this

Please Help me how to do this I'm new in JS

Please give me different kind of solutions its more useful to my career.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: and what should be the result if I call `a(3745)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
function swap (input) {
  if( input == 0)
    return 5;
  return 0;
}
```

i think there is no description needed

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are getting at.

You want to input one variable into a function, and return another variable that is not defined yet. Then you want to define that variable by inputting it into the same function, and get the first input as the output. And so you should end up with 2 outputs.

Now this is technically impossible, because there are undefined variables at play. However, programming is about imagination and I think I have a solution (it's technically a hack but it will work):

```
var i = 1;
var output1;
var output2;
function swap(input) {
    function func1(input) {
        output2 = input;
        i++;
    }
    function func2(input) {
        output1 = input;
        i = 1;
        alert(String(output1) + "\n" + String(output2));
    }
    if (i === 1) {
        func1(input);
    }
    else if (i === 2) {
        func2(input);
    }
}
while(true) {
    swap(prompt("Enter your first input (this will be your second output):"));
    swap(prompt("Enter your second input (this will be your first output):"));
}
```

The `swap` function goes back and forth between the values 1 and 2 in the variable `i`. That is how it keeps track of first or second inputs and their exact opposite outputs. The input, or parameter of the `swap` function is whatever the user types into the prompt boxes. Feel free to make it user-friendly, this is just the dirty code behind it. The reason they are outputted together is because the second input is undefined, and so the machine cannot guess what you were going to input. So first my little program collects all the data and just reverses the order when it is time to output. But to the user who knows nothing about JavaScript and what is going on underneath the hood, this would work perfectly in my opinion.

This should work for any data types inputted, I tested it myself with `objects`, `strings`, `numbers`, and `arrays`. Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter alternative to @mtizziani's answer:

```js
let swap = x => !x * 5 // yes this is all

console.log(swap(0));
console.log(swap(5));
```

- We toggle the input, so `x` is now 1 or 0
- We multiple by 5.

Job done.